# Android: soft keyboard efficient key press effect?

Tags: android, input, performance, android-softkeyboard

on softkeyboard, which one is better to give user a visual feedback during keypress:

1.redraw portion of button that was pressed to background canvas of main `View` to give pressed effect
2.each button has its own "pressed" `View`, and that `View` is set to visible (flashing) during keypress event (so no redraw needed but need more memory)

I know its trade-off between speed and memory usage, but I just want to know what you will do under this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to see the key because your finger will be covering it! The character being added to the focused text field might be enough.

Comment: I think i still need it to give a flash of feedback which button was pressed, it doesn't need to be on the button precisely, it could be like a key preview on top of the button.

Comment: I never use iPhone, how is that?

Comment: Wow, if you do ANY mobile development, you should definitely play with an iPhone/iPod touch. They do a lot of thing right. Whether you like or hate them, Apple has a polish that most developers strive for.